# Can someone please explain this. It deals with malloc and global array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parallel-processing, pthreads

If I'm trying to create a global array to hold an arbitrary number of integers in this case 2 ints. How is it possible that I can assign more numbers to it if I only allocate enough space for just two integers.

```
int *globalarray;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int size = 2; 
    globalarray = malloc(size * sizeof(globalarray[0]));

    // How is it possible to initialize this array pass 
    // the two location that I allocated. 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    globalarray[i] = i;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      printf("%d ", globalarray[i]);
    }
    printf("%s\n", "");

    int arrayLength = sizeof(*globalarray)/sizeof(globalarray[0]);

    printf("Array Length: %d\n", arrayLength);

}
```

When I run this it gives me

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 Array Length: 1
```

So I wanted to know if someone could clarify this for me.

(1) Am I creating the global array correctly?
(2) Why is the array length 1? When I feel that it should be 2 since I malloced the pointer for 2.

And background info on why I want to know this is because I want to create a global array (shared array) so that threads can later access the array and change the values.

Comment: take a look at [`realloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc). And `arrayLength` isn't going to work like that, you'll need to keep track of the number of valid elements you have "manually". `sizeof(*globalArray)` is equivalent to `sizeof(globalArray[0])` which is equivalent to `sizeof(int)`

Comment: C doesn't prevent you from writing before the beginning, or past the end of an array.  It's up to you to do the math correctly.

Answer (score 2):

> How is it possible to initialize this array pass the two location that I allocated.

Short answer: This is undefined behaviour and anything can happen, also the appearance that it worked.

Long answer: You can only initialize the memory you've allocated, it
doesn't matter that the variable is a global variable. C doesn't prevent you from
stepping out of bounds, but if you do, then you get undefined behaviour and anything can happen
(it can "work" but it also can crash immediately or it can crash later).

So if you know that you need 10 `int`s, then allocate memory for 10 `int`.

```
globalarray = malloc(10 * sizeof *globalarray);
if(globalarray == NULL)
{
    // error handling
}
```

And if you later need more, let's say 15, then you can use `realloc` to increase
the memory allocation:

```
globalarray = malloc(10 * sizeof *globalarray);
if(globalarray == NULL)
{
    // error handling
    // do not contiue
}

....
// needs more space

int *tmp = realloc(globalarray, 15 * sizeof *globalarray);
if(tmp == NULL)
{
    // error handling
    // globalarray still points to the previously allocated
    // memory

    // do not continue
}

globalarray = tmp;
```

---

> Am I creating the global array correctly?

Yes and no. It is syntactically correct, but semantically it is not, because you are
allocating space for only 2 `int`s, but it's clear from the next lines that
you need 10 `int`s.

---

> Why is the array length 1? When I feel that it should be 2 since I malloced the pointer for 2.

That's because

```
sizeof(*globalarray)/sizeof(globalarray[0]);
```

only works with arrays, not pointers. Note also that you are using it wrong in
two ways:

1. The correct formula is `sizeof(globalarray) / sizeof(globalarray[0])`
2. This only works for arrays, not pointers (see below)

We sometimes use the term array as a visual representation when we do stuff
like

```
int *arr = malloc(size * sizeof *arr)
```

but `arr` (and `globalarray`) are not arrays,
they are pointers. `sizeof` returns the amount in bytes that the
expression/variable needs. In your case `*globalarray` has type `int` and
`globalarray[0]` has also type `int`. So you are doing `sizeof(int)/sizeof(int)`
which is obviously 1.

Like I said, this only works for arrays, for example, this is correct

```
// not that arr here is not an array
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

size_t len = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0];  // returns 4
```

but this is incorrect:

```
int *ptr = malloc(4 * sizeof *ptr);
size_t len = sizeof ptr / sizeof ptr[0]; // this is wrong
```

because `sizeof ptr` does not returns the total amount of allocated
bytes, it returns the amount of bytes that a pointer needs to be stored in memory. When you are dealing with
pointers, you have to have a separate variable that holds the size.

Answer (score 1):

C does not prevent you from writing outside allocated memory. When coding in C it is of the utmost importance that you manage your memory properly.

For your second question, this is how you would want to allocate your buffer:

```
globalarray = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```

And if you are on an older version of C than c11:

```
globalarray = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```